# Can I replace Windows 8 with Ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8

I currently have a Duel boot process with Windows 7 and 8. I wish to replace 8 with Ubuntu because 8 has been disappointing me greatly. It's taking up space that I could use for something better like, Ubuntu! I was thinking just booting 8 and installing Ubuntu from there but I wanted to make sure. Any advice on this one? I don't want Windows 7 to be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Go to http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop and get a copy of Ubuntu. Burn it to DVD and boot from it. Give it a try, then install it. You will be given a choice as to where to (which partition) you should install and if you want to use it along side Windows.

Make your choices and have a good time. Follow this tutorial  http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/install-ubuntu-with-windows and you should have no problem.

Answer (score 0):

For a better answer provide more information about how your HDD is partitioned and where are your systems installed. But for now I can say that installing ubuntu from windows 8 will put ubuntu as a third option on your select boot screen and you end up having all three OS'es (this depends on what options you chose when installing ubuntu). Then you can manually delete the files of the one you dont want, and edit grub config to display only two options.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by labelling the different partitions for easy identification (Win_7 and Win_8).

Download the Ubuntu iso. Create a liveUSB with [Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) or simply burn a DVD.

Boot from an Ubuntu liveDVD or liveUSB and see if hardware works (Wifi, touchpad, screen brightness control, etc).

If you're satisfied, click the Install Ubuntu icon. Choose the **something else** option. In the partition manager, delete the Win_8 partition, create a small 4GB Swap partition and partition the rest as ext4, mount point /.

Continue with the installation.